# Pycharm - Missing module only when debugging

Tags: debugging, pycharm

PyCharm behaves strange. When click on *run*, the project executes. But click on debug, it fails with a module which could not be found.

This module is a own module importet to python path via the project settings.

Is there a different environment setup for debugging then for running a project? How can I alter the environment for debugging to the same as the run environment?